# Skip a specific number in an array when seeing if array is in decending order

Tags: arrays, loops

For a college assignment, I need to see if an array has each number lower than the previous one. If the number in the array is 142, I need to skip that number and check the next one. My current code, which works for about 90% of the test cases, is this:

```
boolean decreasingExcept2(int[] nums) {
    boolean decending = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; ++i) {
        if ((nums[i] != 142) && (nums[i + 1] != 142) && (nums[i] <= nums[i + 1])) {
            decending = false;
        }

    }

    return decending;
}
```

The problem comes from test cases where there is a 142 between 2 numbers that should make the test case false. This code leaves those kind of arrays true. So arrays like [3, 142, 4] or [3, 142, 142, 3, 0] are sent back true when they are false. How do I get it to compare numbers separated by 142s?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to compare two values by index offset, save the previous value in a variable.

That way, when skipping 142, the previous value remain unchanged. This will therefore even support arrays with multiple consecutive 142's.

Initialize `prev` to the first value, then start iterating at index 1.

Since this is your assignment to complete, I'm not going to show the code. Hope the explanation is adequate to allow you to complete it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've realized that you can't compare adjacent values in the array because of the possibility of meeting a run of one or more intervening 142 values.

The general idea is to remember the last non-142 value you've seen (`prev`), and when you encounter a subsequent non-142 value compare it to `prev`.

Of course, there are complications when an array starts with 142 values. Also, you need to be careful about when you update the value of `prev`.

Here's the approach you need to follow in your code:

1. Initialize `prev` to the value at index 0 and loop from index 1
   through the remainder of the array
2. If `current` is 142 you can't compare it to `prev`, nor should you
   update `prev` to `current`
3. If `current` is not 142, but `prev` is, you can't compare the two.
   But you should update `prev` to `current`.
4. If neither `prev` or `current` are 142 you can compare them and
   return false if they're not decreasing. If they are decreasing you
   need to update `prev` to `current` before continuing.